# How to reconnect to the network using Cordova/phoneGap/Ionic without rebooting the phone?

Tags: java, android, cordova, telecommunication

**Is there a Cordova plugin which resets the network interface?**

I'd like to create an app which runs in the background and periodically (from a remote call) does a few things:

- Reboots mobile hotspot (there's a Cordova plugin for that, easy enough)
- Autostarts the "monitor" software (there's a Cordova plugin for that too, easy enough)
- Reboots the phone.

So think of it as a remote-controlled drone.

Rebooting turns out to be a problem as apps don't have this authority unless the phone is rooted. Rooting it is an option but I'd like to avoid it if I can as I don't know Java very well (and the app has to do a variety of other stuff as I mentioned)

When a reboot happens, the part I'm most interested in is the *network reconnect* at which point the phone receives a new IP. This is where, momentarily, there's no signal and no bars. So I'm thinking if I can trigger that somehow without actually rebooting the phone, I don't need to reboot the phone, as all I want is a fresh IP.

I can't find a Cordova plugin which RESETS the connection to a cell tower.

I don't care if it crashes the network interface or reboots or just sets it to a wrong value which then autocorrects - so long as the phone gets a new IP "on demand," I don't care.

**Is there a Cordova plugin which resets the network interface?**

I know it's possible as I've had issues with my Android where it had to reconnect; but perhaps there's no API to do so on demand.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be hard as the element assigning the IP addresses is not under your control.

Mobile networks are generally set up to have the PDP context, the connection that carries the IP connection, resilient so that they do not just reset when you temporarily lose coverage.

Hence even if you reboot the phone you may be inside the timeout window and still get the same PDP context.

In addition to this, network operators may have an IP address allocation scheme in place, sometimes in association with their NAT tables, that attempts to assign the same IP address to the same device even if it has been idle for some time.

You'll notice on WiFi also that many routers will remember the MAC address and the IP and simply assign the same IP address when they see the same device again.